# How do I remove an anchor element and replace it with a button without damaging the css?

Tags: html, css, button

So, I currently have a list in html, which was originally written to act as hyperlinks, but I want to replace them with buttons, without messing up the css in it's entirety. I've placed in a temporary button element which only works for the selected text inside the list element, but I want it to act for the full element.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="bx bx-grid-alt"></i>
            <button
              class="links_name navlist-btn-dashboard"
              onclick="displayCurrentTab('dashboard')"
            >
              Dashboard
            </button>
          </a>
          <span class="tooltip">Dashboard</span>
        </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar i {
  color: #fff;
  height: 60px;
  min-width: 50px;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}
.sidebar .nav-list {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
.sidebar li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 8px 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebar li .tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: calc(100% + 15px);
  z-index: 3;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0s;
}
.sidebar li:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.sidebar.open li .tooltip {
  display: none;
}
.sidebar li a {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  background: #11101d;
}
.sidebar li a:hover {
  background: #fff;
}
.sidebar li a .links_name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.sidebar.open li a .links_name {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.sidebar li a:hover .links_name,
.sidebar li a:hover i {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  color: #11101d;
}
.sidebar li i {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

I've tried inserting in a button element everystep of the way, but all tries ended in failure as the button element wasn't working.

Comment: a button inside an anchor is invalid. You either need an anchor to redirect to another resource or you need a button to trigger a script. If you need both, add an eventlistener or onclick attribute to the anchor

Comment: I don't require the anchor element, it's just that all the css is tied to it and I want an easy way out

Comment: One option would be to use CSS to style the anchor like a button. You don't need to use Bootstrap, but you could use it as inspiration. See Button Tags - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/ where there is an <a> with the class "btn"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! Just leave it as-is and change all tags from the button element to the anchor element and remove the button function and append it to the anchor element's .onclick(), as in like this:

```
<li>
      <a
        href="#"
        class="navlist-btn-dashboard"
        onclick="displayCurrentTab('dashboard')"
      >
        <i class="bx bx-grid-alt"></i>
        <button class="links_name">Dashboard</button>
      </a>
      <span class="tooltip">Dashboard</span>
    </li>
```